# Fail to open team foundation build process template in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, build-process, azure-devops

I've tried to follow this guide to customize the build process in tfs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx

But after downloading the .xaml file and trying to open it in Visul studio 2013 I get an error:

```
System.Xaml.XamlException: 'The type ‘InArgument(mtbco:BuildParameter[])’ of property ‘AutomatedTests’ could not be resolved.' Line number '5' and line position '39'.
at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.DynamicActivityXamlReader.BufferedPropertyList.ActivityPropertyHolder..ctor(DynamicActivityXamlReader parent, XamlReader reader)
at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.DynamicActivityXamlReader.BufferedPropertyList.BufferDefinitions(DynamicActivityXamlReader parent)
at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.DynamicActivityXamlReader.ProcessCurrentNode()
at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.DynamicActivityXamlReader.Read()
at Microsoft.Activities.Presentation.Xaml.ActivityTemplateFactoryBuilderReader.Read()
at Microsoft.Activities.Presentation.Xaml.ViewStateXamlHelper.StripViewStateElement(XamlReader inputReader, Dictionary`2& viewStateInfo, Dictionary`2& viewStateSourceLocationMap)
at Microsoft.Activities.Presentation.Xaml.ViewStateXamlHelper.ConvertViewStateToAttachedProperties(XamlReader inputReader, ViewStateIdManager idManager, Dictionary`2& viewStateSourceLocationMap)
at Microsoft.Activities.Presentation.Xaml.WorkflowDesignerXamlHelper.DeserializeString(String text, DeserializationMode mode, IList`1& loadErrors, Dictionary`2& sourceLocations)
at Microsoft.Activities.Presentation.Xaml.WorkflowDesignerXamlHelper.DeserializeString(String text, IList`1& loadErrors, Dictionary`2& sourceLocations)
at System.Activities.Presentation.WorkflowDesigner.Load()
```

This is the beginning of the .xaml file:

```
<Activity x:Class="TfsBuild.Process" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common" xmlns:mtbc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client" xmlns:mtbco="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common" xmlns:mtbw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtba="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities" xmlns:mtbac="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities" xmlns:mtbag="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities" xmlns:mtbat="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.TeamFoundation;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities" xmlns:mtbwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mttbb="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.BuildActivities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration" xmlns:mtvc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client" xmlns:mtvco="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sad="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:sad1="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TfsBuild;" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<x:Members>
<x:Property Name="ProjectsToBuild" Type="InArgument(s:String[])" />
<x:Property Name="ConfigurationsToBuild" Type="InArgument(s:String[])" />
<x:Property Name="AutomatedTests" Type="InArgument(mtbco:BuildParameter[])" /> 
<x:Property Name="AdvancedTestSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbco:BuildParameter)" />
<x:Property Name="BuildNumberFormat" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="GetVersion" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="CleanWorkspace" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="CreateLabel" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="AdvancedBuildSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbco:BuildParameter)" />
...
```

It wasn't mentioned in the guide, but I added a reference to "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration" in folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies". But it did not help.

The default template I am using is: "Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml).

Do I need to add some more references?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed the .NET version of the project from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5 and it solved the issue. I can now view the template in both code and design view without error.

Comment: what project? should I change the .NET version to? My build process template XML standalone, not part of any project. ANy idea how to solve this? I get this randomly. I had to restart VS2013 when it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Open the xaml file in an editor of choice, review all xmlns-imports (line-wrapping might help) and add all references to assemblies mentioned in this section.

If you are missing assemblies, you can install the [TFS Object Model package](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6) but respect the version of your TFS. There are special packages for TFS 2013, TFS 2015 and even the "Update" versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older Build template template, you would need to create a Visual Studio Windows Workflow project, add references to the assemblies and add your build template as a link. You will then be able to open and edit your build templates.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did. I created a new project of type "Activity Library" and added the downloaded template to it. I also added all references I found in the activity-tag of the xml file. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Team Foundation Server 2013 so I expect them to be compatible.

Comment: The default template I am using is: "Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml).